# Can't get my panel to save as an image

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, bufferedimage

I made a simple paint program but there seem to be some problems. First off, when I run the program, the components don't show up until I drag my mouse over every single one. Secondly, the drawPanel image I create only saves the background of the panel and not the stuff drawn on it. Another minor issue is the fact that when I change the size of the dots through the drop down menu, whatever was drawn under it gets erased. Any suggestion sot clean up my code or solutions to my issues would be great.

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyPaint extends JFrame implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener {

//initialize coordinates somewhere offscreen
int myX = -100, myY = -100;
private JPanel bucket = new JPanel(new GridLayout(7, 2));
private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
private JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
private String[] pencilSize = {"1", "5", "10", "15", "20"};
private JComboBox sizeList = new JComboBox(pencilSize);
private JButton[] buttons = new JButton[11];
private Color[] colorList = {Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, 
                             Color.WHITE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.GRAY, Color.PINK, Color.BLACK};
private Color currentColor = Color.BLACK;
int radius = 5;
private JLabel thickness = new JLabel("Thickness");
private JButton clear = new JButton("Clear");
private JButton save = new JButton("Save");
private JButton open = new JButton("Open");
private JLabel image = new JLabel(" ");
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();

// *******************  MyPaint **************

public MyPaint(){
    super("MyPaint");
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    setVisible(true);
    setResizable(false);
    sizeList.setEditable(true);
    drawPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
        buttons[i] = new JButton();
        buttons[i].setBackground(colorList[i]);
        buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
        bucket.add(buttons[i]);
    }

    northPanel.add(clear);
    clear.addActionListener(this);
    northPanel.add(thickness);
    northPanel.add(sizeList);
    sizeList.addActionListener(this);
    northPanel.add(open);
    open.addActionListener(this);
    northPanel.add(save);
    save.addActionListener(this);

    add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(bucket, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(northPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}

// *******************  Override of paint **************

//paint the oval at the current location
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.setColor(currentColor);
    if(myX > drawPanel.getX() + 10 && myY > drawPanel.getY() + 25)
        g.fillOval(myX - radius, myY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
}

// *******************  Mouse Events **************

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){
    myX = e.getX();
    myY = e.getY();
    repaint();
}

public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
}
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e){
    myX = e.getX();
    myY = e.getY();
    repaint();
}

public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e){

}

// *******************  Actions **************

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();
    for(int i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++)
        if(source == buttons[i])
            currentColor = colorList[i];

    if(source == clear)
        super.paint(getGraphics());

    else if(source == sizeList)
        radius = Integer.parseInt((String) sizeList.getSelectedItem());

    //open a file
    else if(source == open){
         int returnValue = fc.showOpenDialog(null);
            if (returnValue == fc.APPROVE_OPTION) {
              File sf = fc.getSelectedFile();
              try {
                image.setIcon(new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(sf)));
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
              super.paint(getGraphics());
              drawPanel.add(image);
              drawPanel.revalidate();
              drawPanel.repaint();
            }
    }

    //save a file
    else if(source == save){
        fc.setDialogTitle("Specify a file to save");   

        int userSelection = fc.showSaveDialog(drawPanel);

        if (userSelection == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File fileToSave = fc.getSelectedFile();
            try{
                BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(drawPanel.getWidth(),
                        drawPanel.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_4BYTE_ABGR);
                Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
                drawPanel.printAll(g);
                g.dispose();
                ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("pic.png"));
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }
}

// *******************  Main **************

public static void main(String[] args){
    MyPaint frame = new MyPaint();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}


}
```

Edit:

I replaced paint() with paintComponent() but I still do not know how to draw on it because g.fillOval...() does nothing

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.setColor(currentColor);
    g.fillOval(myX - radius, myY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    if(img != null)
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}
```

Edit 2:

Small version

```
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MySmallPaint extends JPanel implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, ActionListener{

int myX = 0, myY = 0;
int radius = 5;
JPanel drawPanel = new JPanel();
Dimension d = drawPanel.getPreferredSize();
BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(d.width,d.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g = img.createGraphics();

public MySmallPaint(){
    super();
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    //add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponents(g);
    g.fillOval(myX - radius, myY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
    if(img != null)
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    myX = e.getX();
    myY = e.getY();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    myX = e.getX();
    myY = e.getY();
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

public static void main(String[] args){
     JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
     f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
     f.add(new MySmallPaint());
     f.pack();
     f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please understand that we will be much better able to help if you ask a specific and answerable question rather than a vague request to "help me clean up". Please look at the [help] as well as [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to find out how you can improve this question and increase your odds of getting decent answers.

Comment: Note that you don't want to paint directly in a JFrame but rather you will want to paint in the paintComponent method of a JPanel, and you will want to call the super's method first thing within your override. Please read the painting tutorial. You can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/swing/info)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels So what you mean is that every JPanel has its own paint component specific to them? Would I still need an if statement for borders of the JPanel so I don't draw on other components?

Comment: I see that you're calling paint directly -- never do that. You're also getting a component's Graphics object via `getGraphics()`, if you do this, you get a short lived object that can lead to either NullPointerExceptions or images that disappear, so you don't want to do that either. Have you gone through the Swing graphics tutorials yet? If not, you really want to do this and soon.

Comment: Please check: 1) [Lesson: Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html), an introductory tutorial to Swing graphics, and 2) [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html), an advanced tutorial on Swing graphics.

Comment: re `"So what you mean is that every JPanel has its own paint component specific to them?"` - -yes. `"Would I still need an if statement for borders of the JPanel so I don't draw on other components?"` -- not sure what you mean.

Comment: Please note edits to answer. More to come.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem solved:

You're not calling the super's paint method inside of your paint method override and by doing so are not allowing the GUI to draw its own components. In other words, you're not doing this:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
   super.paint(g);  // *************** missing ************
   g.setColor(currentColor);
   if (myX > drawPanel.getX() + 10 && myY > drawPanel.getY() + 25)
      g.fillOval(myX - radius, myY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius);
}
```

But having said this, I also strongly advise you not to draw as you're doing, to instead override the paintComponent method of a JPanel and draw in there. By drawing directly on the JFrame, you risk messing up how it draws itself, its components, its borders, ... as you're finding out. JFrames are complex components complete with many sub components including JRootPanes, contentPanes, JLayeredPanes, glasspanes, ... and you really don't want to risk messing up the drawing of these sub components.

Next, to save the images in your drawing, draw to a BufferedImage, and then display that BufferedImage in your drawing JPanel's (the one with the MouseListener attached) paintComponent, something like:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (myImage != null) {
        g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null);
    }
}
```

So in your mouse listener you draw to this image, using a Graphics obtained from the image by calling either `getGraphics()` or `createGraphics()` on it. The former gets a Graphics object while the latter gets a Graphics2D object. Note that this is not the same as calling `getGraphics()` on a component which is **not recommended** (as per my comment). Note also that any Graphics object obtained in this way should be disposed of when you're through with it so you don't waste resources.

---

> I created a BufferedImage but how do I add it to my drawPanel / JFrame.

Your drawing JPanel can hold the BufferedImage as a field. When you need to draw on it, you get its Graphics context as noted above -- note that I prefer to use `createGraphics()` to get the Graphics2D object so I can use all its goodies such as Strokes. You size the BufferedImage to your JPanel's preferred size, and you draw it as I have shown above.

> I am also unsure as how to draw on the buffered image.

As noted above. Also note that it's usually better to draw lines rather than ovals or ellipses, if you are trying to create a connected drawing

For a simple example, one without all the stuff you're trying to do...

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class SimpleDrawMain extends JPanel {
   private static final int PREF_W = 600;
   private static final int PREF_H = PREF_W;
   private SimpleDrawPanel simpleDrawPanel = new SimpleDrawPanel(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   private MyMouse myMouse = new MyMouse();

   // drawStroke: thickness of lines drawn. Can change this as needed
   private Stroke drawStroke = new BasicStroke(6f);
   // drawColor -- change this as needed
   private Color drawColor = Color.BLUE; 

   public SimpleDrawMain() {
      simpleDrawPanel.addMouseListener(myMouse);
      simpleDrawPanel.addMouseMotionListener(myMouse);
      simpleDrawPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY));

      JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
      topPanel.add(new JButton(new SaveImageAction("Save", KeyEvent.VK_S)));
      topPanel.add(new JButton(new ClearImageAction("Clear", KeyEvent.VK_C)));

      setLayout(new BorderLayout());
      add(topPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
      add(simpleDrawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
   }

   private class MyMouse extends MouseAdapter {
      private Graphics2D g2;
      private Point point; // point to draw a line with

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         if (e.getButton() != MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            return;
         }

         // get our Graphics object to draw with
         g2 = simpleDrawPanel.getMyImage().createGraphics();
         point = e.getPoint();  // get the first point
         g2.setStroke(drawStroke);  // set stroke and color
         g2.setColor(drawColor);
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         if (point == null) {
            return;
         }
         drawOnImage(e);
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         if (point == null) {
            return;
         }
         drawOnImage(e);

         // clean up things
         g2.dispose();
         g2 = null;
         point = null;
      }

      private void drawOnImage(MouseEvent e) {
         // better to draw a line between two points rather than an oval
         // get 2nd point, and then using 2 points, create line to draw
         Point p2 = e.getPoint();
         int x1 = point.x;
         int y1 = point.y;
         int x2 = p2.x;
         int y2 = p2.y;
         g2.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);

         // reset the original point to the new point
         point = p2;

         simpleDrawPanel.repaint();
      }

   }

   private class SaveImageAction extends AbstractAction {
      public SaveImageAction(String name, int mnemonioc) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonioc);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         BufferedImage img = simpleDrawPanel.getMyImage();
         // TODO write code to save img to file         
      }
   }

   private class ClearImageAction extends AbstractAction {
      public ClearImageAction(String name, int mnemonioc) {
         super(name);
         putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonioc);
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
         simpleDrawPanel.clearImage();
      }
   }

   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      SimpleDrawMain mainPanel = new SimpleDrawMain();

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SimpleDraw");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setResizable(false);
      frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}

class SimpleDrawPanel extends JPanel {
   // preferred size dimensions for this JPanel
   private int prefW;
   private int prefH;
   // image to draw on
   private BufferedImage myImage;

   public SimpleDrawPanel(int prefW, int prefH) {
      this.prefW = prefW;
      this.prefH = prefH;
      myImage = new BufferedImage(prefW, prefH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
   }

   public BufferedImage getMyImage() {
      return myImage;            
   }

   public void clearImage() {
      // simply create a new BufferedImage
      myImage = new BufferedImage(prefW, prefH, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
      repaint();
   }

   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(prefW, prefH);
   }

   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       if (myImage != null) {
           g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null);
       }
   }

}
```

Comment: I created a BufferedImage but how do I add it to my drawPanel / JFrame. I am also unsure as how to draw on the buffered image.

Comment: When I call g.fillOval(myX - radius, myY - radius, 2 * radius, 2 * radius); and then repaint(); directly in mouseClicked nothing shows up.

Comment: @AlexMarkenzon: Best thing for you to do, is if you're having problems, create a **small** compilable and runnable program that demonstrates your problem for us.

Comment: I added a smaller version up top

Comment: @AlexMarkenzon: You haven't followed my  recommendations it seems -- you're still painting directly in the JFrame, a class that doesn't even have a paintComponent method to override (that's why the compiler wouldn't let you call a super method, and you instead called the totally unrelated paintComponents method). Please re-read my recommendations, please re-look at my code example. You can solve this, but it is going to require some effort.

Comment: @AlexMarkenzon: and please read the painting tutorials that I've linked to in comments quite a while ago. This is all explained there as well.

Comment: I changed the small version now to use a JPanel but for some reason there is a small black box at the top left and the size of the frame won't change when I call setSize(1000, 1000);

Comment: @AlexMarkenzon: I'm going to let you debug this for now, since I've got some work to catch up on. I have full confidence in your ability to solve this thing. Keep at it.

Comment: I fixed the size problem. Thanks for your help, I will attempt to convert of main code to JPanel now. Your suggestions were very helpful.